# Print a specific word from a string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I found a few solutions similar to my question but they are not helpful. I have an array list containing few string values { "Apple", "Banana", "AppleBanana" }

I want to be able to extract Apple from each string. Below is an extraction word "Apple". But how do I extract Apple from AppleBanana word?

```
string[] listOfString = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" };
var query = from string i in listOfString
            group i by (i == "Apple") into appleString
            select appleString;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    if (item.Key == true)
    {
        string[] Applyby = item.ToArray();

        foreach (var item2 in item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output, after extraction?

Comment: Instead of `i == "Apple"` use `i.Contains("Apple")`, in general, you can figure out this sort of stuff by reading the documentation or even by playing with intellisense in visual studio.

Comment: I am looking to display Apple Apple.

Comment: using i.Contains("Apple") gives me AppleBanana too. I do not want to display Banana.

Comment: What means "extract"? You have already the word you search, so there's nothing to _extract_. Also, if your expected output is `Apple Apple` you don't want to find the `Apple` in `AppleBanana`. Can you explain the rules better?

Comment: So should `{ "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" }` result in `{ "Apple", "Apple" }` or `{ "Apple", "Apple", "Apple" }`?

Comment: @TicketForLessUK give the clarification ask by Corak

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
string[] listOfString = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" };
var AppleItems = listOfString.Where(x => x.Equals("Apple"));
foreach (string item in AppleItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

returns `Apple Apple`

Comment: @TicketForLessUK did you try my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using C# [Regex Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string text = "AppleBanana";
Regex pattern = new Regex( "Apple" );
Match match = pattern.Match( text );

string value = groups[ 1 ].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] listOfString = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" };
            string searchStr="Apple";
            int count=0;
            foreach (string subStr in listOfString)
            { 
            if (subStr.Contains(searchStr))
                count +=1;
            }
     Console.WriteLine("The occurence of " & searchStr & "is :" &  count);
 // here count give the number of apples in the array
```

Or else you can extract the words that contains `Apple` as like the following:

```
            string[] listOfString = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" };
            string searchStr="Apple";   
       Console.WriteLine("The following strings contains the word : " & searchStr );
            foreach (string subStr in listOfString)
            {
                if (subStr.Contains(searchStr))
                     Console.WriteLine(subStr);
            }
```

Comment: Both your solutions gives me blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also want to find substrings. Then you can't use `==` but either `String.Contains` or `String.IndexOf`. The latter has the advantage that you can make it case-insensitive easily.

[`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
var allWithApple = listOfString.Where(word => word.Contains("Apple"));
```

[`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var allWithApple = listOfString
    .Where(word => word.IndexOf("apple", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

You can execute the LINQ queries with a `foreach` or create a new `String[]` with `ToArray`.

```
foreach(string wordWithApple in allWithApple)
    Console.WriteLine( wordWithApple );
```

Comment: Not helping @Tim, I am still getting results with AppleBanana.

Comment: @TicketForLessUK: remember your own words: _"But how do I extract Apple from AppleBanana word"_. If you don't want it you dont need to search substrings. Then you can use `==` or `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] listOfWords = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" }; //this is case-sensitive
listOfWords.Where(x => x.Contains("Apple")).Select(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

This will print Apple Apple AppleBanana (in new lines). 
If you want just "Apple" for all the words, you can simply hard code that.

```
string[] listOfWords = { "Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "AppleBanana" };
listOfWords.Where(x => x.Contains("Apple")).Select(a => Console.WriteLine("Apple"));
```